# How can I merge two (or more) TensorFlow datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I have fetched the CelebA datasets with 3 partitions as follows

```
>>> celeba_bldr = tfds.builder('celeb_a')
>>> datasets = celeba_bldr.as_dataset()
>>> datasets.keys()
dict_keys(['test', 'train', 'validation'])

ds_train = datasets['train']
ds_test = datasets['test']
ds_valid = datasets['validation']
```

Now, I want to merged them all into one dataset. For example, I would need to combine the train and validaiton together, or possibly, merge all of them together and then split them based on different subject-disjoint criterion of my own. Is there anyway to do that?

I could not find any option to do this in the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the docs you linked, dataset seems to have `concatenate` method, so I'd presume you can get a joint dataset as:

```
ds_train = datasets['train']
ds_test = datasets['test']
ds_valid = datasets['validation']

ds = ds_train.concatenate(ds_test).concatenate(ds_valid)
```

See: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#concatenate

Answer (score 8):

I want to also mention that if you need to concatenate **multiple** datasets (e.g., list of datasets), you can do in a more efficient way:

```py
ds_l = [ds_1, ds_2, ds_3] # list of `Dataset` objects

# 1. create dataset where each element is a `tf.data.Dataset` object
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds_l)

# 2. extract all elements from datasets and concat them into one dataset
concat_ds = ds.interleave(
    lambda x: x,
    cycle_length=1,
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
)
```

You can also use `flat_map()` but I suppose using `interleave()` with parallel calls is faster. In general `interleave` is a generalization of`flat_map`.

Answer (score 0):

If the datasets are comming from the same TFDS dataset, you can merge them directly with the split API:

```py
ds = tfds.load('celeb_a', split='train+test+validation')
```

Or use special `all` split:

```py
ds = tfds.load('celeb_a', split='all')
```

Documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits